# Create a math quiz with LaTex by randomly choosing questions from a bank

Tags: exams, testing

I am looking for a simple solution to the following problem:

I would like to create a math quiz with n questions via LaTex (printable, in pdf) where question 1 is chosen randomly from question bank #1, question 2 is chosen randomly form question bank #2, etc.

Is there a simple way to do so? Thanks in advance.

Andrea

Comment: You might have better success asking at tex.stackexchange.com. For example, see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151375/how-to-generate-random-variables-then-use-in-calculations-in-pdflatex

Comment: @BrendanW.Sullivan very very cool. Thanks for mentioning that site.

Answer (score 7):

As Brandon mentioned in a comment, I'm working to develop an online platform for this use-case, where the banks are generated using SageMath code and [PreTeXt XML](https://pretextbook.org). Problem sets for linear algebra and differential equations are available to the public at https://checkit.clontz.org/ and I'll be working to add better support for new authors in the near future. The community for the CheckIt platform is on the #checkit-app channel of the [Mastery Grading Slack](https://www.masterygrading.com/resources).

Answer (score 7):

So in theory different students could get different questions?  The software I know of that does this is WeBWorK.  It will even score student-entered answers for you.  See [LINK](https://webwork.maa.org) . Supported by the Mathematical Association of America.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done, although I haven't worked out a model to show how. Latex/Tex is a programming language in the sense that one can declare and initialize variables (\newcounter, \setcounter), iterate (there are while loops), and use conditionals (\ifthenelse). Additionally, one caan call a random number generator (I don't habitually use this, but I think it is \rand). Combined with \input, \include or some similar tool these ingredients are sufficient to write a latex file that generates an exercise sheet with problems drawn randomly from a bank.